# Gaining Reference to the Dialog from Dialog content

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Here's my scenario:

1. I've got a div on Page A.
2. When an event happens (whatever I define, a click, whatever), I do a div.Dialog, set its properties and open it
3. The data inside is returned from an async .ajax call that grabs the data from a url and appends it to the div by calling div.html(data) inside the .ajax callback, so it's essentially loading a PageB by getting the data (content) and appending it to the div that's calling the dialog("open")...nothing special here I don't think.

**My question:** In Page B, how do I reference the dialog so I can do some things to it?  For instance in Page B's content that I received back from that .ajax call and added to the div via .html(data), there is a button and when clicked I need to close the dialog.

Right now my buttons are not working inside the dialog because one of them closes out the dialog and the other should redirect to a new page but both do not work now because I have no reference to the dialog that it's in to manipulate it.  So I need reference so I can close the dialog via some jQuery that will reside in PageB (data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Page B is loaded by AJAX (as opposed to an `<iframe>`), any Javascript in it will run in the same context as the rest of Page A.

Therefore, you can use the same code you use in Page A to reference the dialog in Page B.
Note that if Page B is also used elsewhere, you'll need to check that you're actually running inside of Page A first.  (Check whether the dialog exists, or some variable set in Page A)

---

### EDIT

If it is in an `<iframe>`, you can interact with the parent frame using the `parent` property.

Specifically, you can run jQuery code in the context of the parent frame using `parent.$`.
For example:

```
parent.$('#someId').dialog(...);
```

Since this uses the `$` function from the parent page, Page B does not need to reference jQuery or jQuery UI.  The selectors would be matched within the parent page.

You could (but shouldn't) run the parent page's jQuery code against the child page by writing `parent.$('selector', document)`

Comment: Page B's content is wrapped in an IFrame.  So when I grab the data from whatever url, I wrap it in an IFrame as part of that data and that's what is appened to the div, then I call my div.dialog("open") in the end.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Then you can interact with the parent page using the `parent` property.  (eg, `parent.$('...').dialog(...)`)

Comment: Note that I haven't tested that.

Comment: You should ask a separate question.

Comment: I have, I swear it was working last night, then I come into work and wtf, it's not anymore.  Who knows...frustrating.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646186/not-able-to-close-dialog-from-parent-dialog-reference

Comment: is parent. a shortcut for $(this). ?  how can you use just parent. without any $ before it?

Comment: parent is the parent frame's window object, whic contains all functions and variables from the parent frame.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in Page A in the success ajax callback because it is Page A that has reference to the `div` that needs to be closed.

Page A:

```
$('div.Dialog').load('/pageB', function(data) {
    $('#closeButtonOnPageB').click(function() {
        // ... close dialog
    });
});
```

Comment: what does load have to do with this?  I am setting the div's inner html by using the jQuery .html after I get the data back from my .ajax call...then opening the dialog.

Comment: You mentioned AJAX with jQuery, load is one way to do it, butmaybe you are using something else like `$.ajax`, `$.get`, `$.post`, etc... but in all cases you've got a success callback in which you could register the close event.

Comment: but I do not want to close on callback.  Only when the user clicks a button in the content of my dialog.